# Highchart tooltip displays the right color but line chart doesnt

Tags: typescript, highcharts

I am trying to make a candlestick chart and add a moving average where I would like the color of the line to be red when the moving average is > closing price and green else wise. I am using the highchart library. I have noticed that when I scroll with my mouse across the moving average on the tooltip it has assigned the right color However the actual line on the chart is either staying a single color or has random changes which are too infrequent to be matching up with the data. For example, it may change color 3 or 4 times incorrectly where the color should not change whereas the underlying data changes more like 10 times. I had success using zones for the volume chart.

```
chartRef.current.chart.addSeries({
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Volume',
        data: volumeData,
        yAxis: 1,
        showInLegend: false,
        zoneindex: 0,
        zones: volumeData.map((data, i) => {
            const candlestick = candlestickData[i];
            const color = candlestick[1] < candlestick[4] ? 'green' : 'red';
            return {
              value: data[1],
              color: color,
   
            };
        }),
        
      });
```

But when I try apply similar logic to my moving average it doesn't work despite the tooltip working and applying the correct colors.

```
const maData = [];
    for (let i = 19; i < candlestickData.length; i++) {
    const sum = candlestickData
        .slice(i - 19, i + 1)
        .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr[4], 0);
    const maPrice = parseFloat((sum / 20).toFixed(2));
    const closePrice = candlestickData[i][4];
    const color = maPrice > closePrice ? 'red' : 'green';
    maData.push({ x: candlestickData[i][0], y: maPrice,color: color });
    }

    chartRef.current.chart.addSeries({
        type: 'line',
        name: '20-Day MA Price',
        data: maData,
        yAxis: 0,
        lineWidth: 3,
        zoneindex: 1,
        zones: maData.map((data, i) => {
            
            return {
                
              value: data.y,
              color: data.color,
   
            };
        }),
      
       
      });
```

Comment: Hi @JPWilson, Could you reproduce the problem in some minimal live example? Here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lup9s0gw/ I've prepared an environment which you can use as a base to start.